# Where do I place the Admin user in the menu?

Tags: user-behavior, navigation, menu, administration

I am redesigning a platform with two kinds of users: regular and Admin and the two roles are not separated, meaning the Admin should see the same as the regular user + the Admin button, which takes them to their dashboard.

**The Admin button has to be prominently placed, and VERY accessible**. In the old design, the Admin link was placed right after the page's names, in the bottom navigation panel, which I don't find intuitive at all. But where should I place it?

[image: User navigation menu]

[image: Admin navigation menu]

I'm afraid that placing the Admin next to My account would hide it too much, but next to "My balance" is also weird.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If a normal user doesn't see the admin button, why do you need the admin button in the first place? Isn't it possible to display a link to the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the relative visual design and placement of the button, I don't think that there's any chance the user is going to miss it wherever you place it. As long as it is in a fixed spot, users will learn to remember where it is and where to go look for it.

There are some different ways to think about the logical placement of this button, depending on your initial design concept.

Firstly, if you want to make the distinction at the top level of different types of users, then I think it makes sense to be near where top level account functions are located.

Alternatively, if you want to make the distinction at the feature level of the application, then it can work more like a toggle to turn certain features on and off. In this case, you can place it where those features will appear or where the user will access them.